# iOS 9 UIWebView Crash When Loading

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

I have an Url http://m3.jusfoun.com/app2.0/html2.0/czxfx.html?ent_id=2497283&userid=14304
I scroll web view  down always when the url is not loaded completely,then it is crash on iOS 9

```
 let url=NSURL(string: "http://m3.jusfoun.com/app2.0/html2.0/czxfx.html?ent_id=2497283&userid=14304")
 let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
 mywebview.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: anyone can help me to catch that bug